# How to calculate correlation coefficient for the 3 scenarios?

Tags: r, correlation

Scenario 1:

```
x=c(1,2,3,4)
y=c(2,2,2,2)
```

Scenario 2:

```
x=c(3,3,3,3)
y=c(2,2,2,2)
```

Scenario 3:

```
x=c(3,3,3,3)
y=c(3,3,3,3)
```

In R, when I used "cor(method="kendall")":

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In cor(x, y, method = "kendall") : the standard deviation is zero
```

Note: all values are ordinal.

From my point of view, at least for Scenario 3, the "corr coef" should be 1 as the two sets of values perfectly match.

Comment: Correlation is a measure of synchronous change, not strict similarity.  If one or both vectors have no variance, there can't be a correlation.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45898360/2799941).

Comment: Yes. I understand that. I think the issue might finally boil down to the limitation of correlation coefficient.